# How to solve the conda virtual env and system env conflict on import cv2?

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc, paths, conda

I have installed opencv 3.4.1 correctly on my system enviroment.

But after I create a conda virtual environment using opencv3.2.0, it leads some problems here:

**Under the conda virtual env,** I have to always first

```
cd myenv/lib/python3.5/site_packages/
```

such that import cv2 is correctly using the 3.2.0 version of opencv.

**Under the conda base enviroment** import cv2 using opencv 3.4.1 version.

**Under the system enviroment**, i.e first comment the PATH to anaconda3, then import cv2 will lead to segmentation fault.

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the PATH in .profile like you do in .bashrc too, so apps will try to find lib installed in conda envs as well.